# bootstrap js not loading asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <script>

        $("button").click(function () {
            alert("funny");
            var $btn = $(this);
            $btn.button('loading');
            // Then whatever you actually want to do i.e. submit form
            // After that has finished, reset the button state using
            setTimeout(function () {
                $btn.button('reset');
            }, 1000);
        });
</script>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>



    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>






    </form>
    <button type="button" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">
  Loading state
</button>


</body>
</html>
```

this is my simple code..
i have confirmed that jquery should load first then bootstrap.. still its not loading

Comment: Debug using your browser dev tools so you can identify what you mean by "still not loading".

Comment: i dont know how to use that dev tool (f12). not loading means, that button is not working. i am sure it is related jscript/jquery as css is working fine